# Multi-permissions with Rolify gem for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rolify

I have a doubt about the Rolify Gem for Ruby on Rails.

I want to create permissions for especified Organizations, for example,

I have the Admin Permission for Organization 1 (`Organization.find(1)`)

I have the User Permission for Organization 2 (`Organization.find(2)`)

I have the Moderator Permission for Organization 3 (`Organization.find(3)`)

The Organizations are separated by Client, and I could have many different permissions in many different Organizations.

I tried to use the in the log `user.add_role "full_admin", Organization.find(1)` for example, and it not have the functionality that I hope.
In the DB this query of Rolify armazened is the follow,

```html
2.1.5 :111 > user.add_role "full_admin", Organization.find(1)
  Organization Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `organizations`.* FROM `organizations` WHERE `organizations`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Role Load (1.2ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` WHERE `roles`.`name` = 'full_admin' AND `roles`.`resource_type` = 'Organization' AND `roles`.`resource_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Role Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `users_roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `users_roles`.`role_id` WHERE `users_roles`.`user_id` = 1 AND `roles`.`id` = 7 LIMIT 1
 => #<Role id: 7, name: "full_admin", resource_id: 1, resource_type: "Organization", created_at: "2017-01-06 19:58:31", updated_at: "2017-01-06 19:58:31">
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolify allows you scoped roles as shown in the following code. I have copied it from Rolify wiki.

```
user = User.find(2)
user.add_role :moderator, Forum.first # sets a role scoped to a resource instance
user.has_role? :moderator, Forum.first
=> true
user.has_role? :moderator, Forum.last
=> false
```

As you can see from above code, you can set different roles for different organization. You can consider using a library like "[Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)" for setting permissions based on role.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer, I may have done something wrong so, I will can look my code again, and if I has other doubt, I contact you, thanks.